# angular assign variable to $scope failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

In controller,I can get a response message from node server.but assign is failed.
controller:

```
.controller('someCtrl', function(exportExcel){
    $scope.clickEvent = function(){
      exportExcel.postData( function(msg){
        console.log(msg.downloadURL)  //output download file's path.Get from nodejs response.
        $scope.downloadlink = msg.downloadURL;
        angular.element('download').click();  //dowload automatically,but do not work.
   }) 
    }
});
```

view:

```
<a ng-click="clickEvent()">Export Excel</a>
<a ng-href="{{downloadlink}}" target="_blank" id="download" ng-hide="true"> Download </a>
```

`ng-href` can not get `$scope.downloadlink`, when I clicked again, It can get.

Comment: What is outputted on your console?

Comment: @Ashesh `res.send(200,{downloadURL:'/download/test.xlxs'})` , so console outputted '/download/test.xlxs'

Comment: shouldn't it be: `angular.element('#download').click()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you update controller's scope, the view **is not updated yet** util the next cycle.

You could workaround this by wrapping inside $timeout, and angular.element does not support selector, you could try `document.getElementById` or include jQuery in page and use jQuery selector:

```
$timeout(function(){
   document.getElementById('download').click(); 
   //$("#download").click();
});
```

Remember to inject it into the controller:

```
.controller('someCtrl', function(exportExcel,$timeout){
```

I suggest another solution to download the file by including a hidden iframe on the page:

```
<iframe id="download" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

And set it `src` like this:

```
 document.getElementById('download').src = msg.downloadURL;
 //$("#download").attr("src",msg.downloadURL);
```

Comment: @Ryan Yiada: actually, you could also use javascript `setTimeout` in place of `$timeout` because you're manipulating the DOM directly, don't need to go though angular.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure your selector is wrong:

```
  angular.element('download').click();
```

should be

```
  angular.element('#download').click();
```